# How to design SMTP mail content in c#

Tags: c#, api, smtp

Software that I'm developing right now sends e-mail to responsible when a problem occurs in a production line. However while doing this email,I prefer it with a design like a card not a normal string.

I have just a little knowledge HTML and tried it but result was terrible.
So is there any API for c# to make this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this sample. May be it can help you.

```
MailAddress addressFrom = new MailAddress("jack.du@e-iceblue.com", "Jack Du");
MailAddress addressTo = new MailAddress("susanwong32@outlook.com");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(addressFrom, addressTo);

message.Date = DateTime.Now;
message.Subject = "Sending Email with HTML Body";
string htmlString = @"<html>
                  <body>
                  <p>Dear Ms. Susan,</p>
                  <p>Thank you for your letter of yesterday inviting me to come for 
 an interview on Friday afternoon, 5th July, at 2:30.I shall be happy to be there as 
 requested and will bring my diploma and other papers with me.</p>
                  <p>Sincerely,<br>-Jack</br></p>
                  </body>
                  </html>
                 ";   
message.BodyHtml = htmlString;

 SmtpClient client= new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.outlook.com";
client.Port = 587;
client.Username = addressFrom.Address;
client.Password = "password";
client.ConnectionProtocols = ConnectionProtocols.Ssl;
client.SendOne(message);

Console.WriteLine("Sent Successfully!");
Console.Read();
```

Comment: I used something similar to this, however it is still "basic" for me. I want to design the content somehow. For example think about registration forms. There are some constant things on the left and information on right side. And all this with a simple design

Comment: May be I don't understand your question. When your system got a problem and email to responsible person. If you want to make a format then design a form as you wish then you have to send this form to responsible person as a attached file. Hence you need to make this form pdf or image file before sending.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below property in order to get your content in the Html format.

> message.IsBodyHtml = true;

Hope this is helpful